# Missing Data in mysql query, Need conditional statement in inner join

Tags: mysql

I have been having issues with missing data when I run the following query. 
There are some products which has special price, stored in table `oc_product_special` and some products has regular price stored in table `oc_product`.

I figured out that it is only showing data if there is a special price in table `oc_product_special`. it is omitting any data where there is no special price and only regular price. I am not sure how to fix this problem. How and where i can add conditional statement or something like

> if there is a regular price present and no special price then show regular price and 0 for special price.

```
SELECT       
        pd.name AS 'Product Name', 
        p.model AS UPC,  
        p.quantity AS 'Quantity', 
        p.price AS 'Regular Price', 
        ps.price AS 'Special Price', 
        p.cost AS 'COST', 
        p.status AS 'Status'
FROM oc_product p
    INNER JOIN oc_product_description pd
        ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
    INNER JOIN oc_product_special ps
        ON ps.product_id = p.product_id
    INNER JOIN oc_manufacturer m
        ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
    INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c 
        ON p2c.product_id = p.product_id
    INNER JOIN oc_category c 
        ON c.category_id = p2c.category_id
    INNER JOIN oc_category_description cd 
        ON c.category_id = cd.category_id
WHERE 
      c.category_id = 37 OR c.parent_id = 37
GROUP BY pd.name ORDER BY m.name ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`, which will retain records on the left side of the join even if they do not match to anything on the right side:

```
SELECT COALESCE(pd.name, 'NA') AS 'Product Name', 
       p.model AS UPC,  
       p.quantity AS 'Quantity', 
       p.price AS 'Regular Price', 
       COALESCE(ps.price, 0.0) AS 'Special Price', 
       p.cost AS 'COST', 
       p.status AS 'Status'
FROM oc_product p
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd
    ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN oc_product_special ps
    ON ps.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_manufacturer m
    ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c 
    ON p2c.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_category c 
    ON c.category_id = p2c.category_id
INNER JOIN oc_category_description cd 
    ON c.category_id = cd.category_id
WHERE c.category_id = 37 OR
      c.parent_id = 37
GROUP BY pd.name
ORDER BY m.name
```

**Explanation:**

In a `LEFT JOIN`, when a record on the left side of the join does *not* match to anything on the right side, the columns from the right side will all appear as `NULL` in the result set.  I used the `COALESCE` function in my query, which will conditionally replace the first argument with the second if the former be `NULL`.  In this case, the special price will be replaced with zero if `NULL`.  I also used it with the product name in case names be missing in some cases.

Comment: Thank you. I got to learn 2 very important things, 1st is about left join and second about COALESCE function. This one fixed the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use left join on oc_product_special

```
    SELECT       
            pd.name AS 'Product Name', 
            p.model AS UPC,  
            p.quantity AS 'Quantity', 
            p.price AS 'Regular Price', 
            ps.price AS 'Special Price', 
            p.cost AS 'COST', 
            p.status AS 'Status'
    FROM oc_product p
        INNER JOIN oc_product_description pd
            ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
        LEFT  JOIN oc_product_special ps
            ON ps.product_id = p.product_id
        INNER JOIN oc_manufacturer m
            ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
        INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c 
            ON p2c.product_id = p.product_id
        INNER JOIN oc_category c 
            ON c.category_id = p2c.category_id
        INNER JOIN oc_category_description cd 
            ON c.category_id = cd.category_id
    WHERE 
          c.category_id = 37 OR c.parent_id = 37
    GROUP BY pd.name ORDER BY m.name ASC
```

Inner join si for matching value in you case somethings there aren't match so ..use left join